# What is the correct mime type for html5 documents?

Tags: html, mime-types

I'm pretty certain that it's more relaxed than xhtml was years ago, but Google's not burping up any definitive answers in the first few pages, and SO doesn't seem to have this either.

When I use the mime database on my files, it's coming back as "text/html", but that just makes me wonder if I've somehow got those malformed rather than it being the correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

`text/html` is what you're looking for.  Additionally, it's recommended that you set the character set in the `Content-Type` header:

```
text/html; charset=utf-8
```

https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index

Answer (score 2):

You're right. text/html is correct.